# How to sum time intervals by days: How many intervals include a given day?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a very large data set of time intervals (start and end date values), and need to calculate for every single day within the entire range of those dates how many of the intervals include the date.

In essence, I want to know how many people are in jail any given day.  I have when they entered, and when they left.  I need to be able to determine how many were in jail on every single day over a period of many years.

Example data:

```r
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)

x <- tribble(~start, ~end,
        today()-5, today()-3,
        today()-4, today()-2,
        today()-3, today()-1)


x <- x %>% mutate(dtint = interval(start, end))
x
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   start      end        dtint                         
#>   <date>     <date>     <Interval>                    
#> 1 2019-10-13 2019-10-15 2019-10-13 UTC--2019-10-15 UTC
#> 2 2019-10-14 2019-10-16 2019-10-14 UTC--2019-10-16 UTC
#> 3 2019-10-15 2019-10-17 2019-10-15 UTC--2019-10-17 UTC

mydays <- seq(min(x$start), max(x$end), by = "day") %>% enframe(name = NULL, value = "eachday")
mydays
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>   eachday   
#>   <date>    
#> 1 2019-10-13
#> 2 2019-10-14
#> 3 2019-10-15
#> 4 2019-10-16
#> 5 2019-10-17

#Expected result:
mydays %>% add_column(expected_result = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   eachday    expected_result
#>   <date>               <dbl>
#> 1 2019-10-13               1
#> 2 2019-10-14               2
#> 3 2019-10-15               3
#> 4 2019-10-16               2
#> 5 2019-10-17               1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I will also need the ability to do this on grouped tibbles so I can calculate things like totals by demographic properties.

Is there an efficient way to do this in tidyverse/lubridate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach of how you could track totals using the cumulative count across each grouped demographic.

```
# Example data
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
x <- tibble(demographic = sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = T),
            start = as.Date("2019-01-01") + runif(100, 0, 30),
            end = start + runif(100, 1, 50))
## A tibble: 6 x 3
#  demographic start      end       
#  <chr>       <date>     <date>    
#1 C           2019-01-19 2019-03-05
#2 C           2019-01-07 2019-02-02
#3 A           2019-01-07 2019-02-19
#4 C           2019-01-12 2019-02-04
#5 B           2019-01-29 2019-02-07
#6 B           2019-01-29 2019-02-21
```

First we bring it into long format. Then count each start date as incrementing up, each end date incrementing down. Then we group by demographic and take the cumulative total of those increments up and down.

```
x %>%
  pivot_longer(-demographic, "col", values_to = "date") %>%
  mutate(change = if_else(col == "start", 1, -1)) %>%
  arrange(demographic, date) %>%
  group_by(demographic) %>%
  mutate(count = cumsum(change)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  ggplot(aes(date, count, color = demographic)) +
  geom_step()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option involving `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `lubridate` could be:

```
x %>%
 mutate(eachday = list(seq.Date(min(start), max(end), by = "1 day"))) %>%
 unnest(eachday) %>%
 group_by(eachday) %>%
 summarise(overlap = sum(int_overlaps(dtint, interval(eachday, eachday))))

  eachday    overlap
  <date>       <int>
1 2019-10-13       1
2 2019-10-14       2
3 2019-10-15       3
4 2019-10-16       2
5 2019-10-17       1
```

First, it creates a list of dates between the first and last date in the data and unnest it. Then, it groups by the dates and sums the overlap between the dtint interval and the interval for dates.

Comment: Thanks.  While this works on small data, for larger data (I have 10 years and tens of thousands of intervals to check) it expands to a massive tibble and takes ages to run.

Comment: I see. Will think about faster possibilities :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`0, create the `seq` column from `min` of 'start' and `max` of 'end' , then join with the original dataset using a non-equi join and get the count (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[x[, .(eachday = seq(min(start), max(end), by = '1 day'))],
        .(eachday, overlap = .N), on = .(start <= eachday,
            end >= eachday ), by = .EACHI][, .(eachday, overlap)]
#       eachday overlap
#1: 2019-10-13       1
#2: 2019-10-14       2
#3: 2019-10-15       3
#4: 2019-10-16       2
#5: 2019-10-17       1
```